# CListCtrl displays inserted item multiple times

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

`CMyListCtrl` is in virtual data mode and owner draw. A `LVN_GETDISPINFO` notification gets sent when the control wants data.

The code below works fine except it displays each line multiple times.

The documentation says that if I set the item's mask's `LVIF_DI_SETITEM` flag, it won't do this. The docs also say the `pItem->iGroupId` must be set before the `InsertItem` which I have done too, but the control still displays many lines for each inserted line.

```
void CMyListCtrl::OnLvnGetdispinfo(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
  NMLVDISPINFO *pDispInfo = reinterpret_cast<NMLVDISPINFO*>(pNMHDR);

  //Create a pointer to the item
  LV_ITEM* pItem= &(pDispInfo)->item;
  CString text, strippedText;

  //Does the control need text information?
  if( pItem->mask & LVIF_TEXT )
  {
    if(pItem->iSubItem == 0) // only first column used
    {
      text.Format( L"%s", cacheNotifyVect[ cacheNdx ] );

      //Copy the text to the LV_ITEM structure
      lstrcpyn(pItem->pszText, text, pItem->cchTextMax);
      pItem->mask |= LVIF_DI_SETITEM; // documentation says to set this so the list-view control will store the requested data and will not ask for it again. The application must set the iGroupid member of the LVITEM structure.
    }
  }

  *pResult = 0;
}

void CMyListCtrl::AddNotifyString(const CString & outListStr)
{
  cacheNotifyVect[ cacheNdx % CACHE_CAPACITY] = outListStr; // RT:130908: make cache round robin for notify
  LVITEM item;
  item.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
  item.iItem = cacheNdx++;
  item.iSubItem = 0;
  item.iGroupId = I_GROUPIDNONE; // so control will store data internally
  item.pszText = (LPTSTR)(LPCTSTR)( outListStr );
  outputWnd->outputNotify.InsertItem( &item );
```

Answer (score 0):

You've set item.mask to LVIF_TEXT, so only the iItem member is being observed and the iGroupId member is being ignored. Set item.mask to LVIF_TEXT|LVIF_GROUPID.

Comment: It turns out that I had not properly implemented the scroll button. So when I scrolled up or down, lines would get "repeated" on the screen.